# jQuery - Animated height set causes trembling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I've never experienced something like this before. When I animate the height and width of a div with jQuery, at the end of the animation the text inside (and maybe the div itself) keeps trembling somehow.

The code looks like this:

```
$('#divid').animate({
    height: size+'px', 
    width: size+'px', 
    top: (window.innerHeight/3) + 'px', 
    left: ((window.innerWidth/2)-(size/2)) + 'px'
});
divid.style.fontSize = size*0.032 + 'px';
```

`size` is calculated from the height or the width of the window.

Have you ever experienced something like this? What could be the solution?

**Update:**
The problem is solved now: the `size` variable caused the problem because it isn't always a whole number (it is a percent of window height or width). I solved it with putting it inside `Math.round()`. Now the animation works fine. :)

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the effect in a [snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You're not telling all: if it's moving, var size is fluctuating, and it's not included in your example

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem once. Please check if your div has any top or bottom margin. If it does, the trembling is caused by the margin. To solve this, remove the margin and give padding instead, then the trembling would stop.

Comment: Meanwhile I solved the problem, the `size` variable must be a whole number. But thanks for the advice, I will remember this. :)

Comment: @nimesulide - Thanks. I got to know another problem that can cause trembling :P